# Catch exceptions caught in nested script php

Tags: php, exception

I run nested scripts from include() in one master script.
I want to know if any errors happened while nested script was executing and log them even if the were caught in try/catch of nested script.

Is that possible?

EDIT:

I'll explain.

I have script _run.php

```
try {

   $i = 1/0;
} catch Exception $e {

}
```

I nest it in another script:

```
$errors = 0;
$errorMessages = '';

try {

    include('_run.php');

} catch (Exception $e) {

    $errors ++;
    $errorMessages .= $e->getTraceAsString();
}

echo $errors; //0
echo $errorMessages; // ''
```

Why $errors and $errorMessages not filled?

Comment: *Is that possible?* Try it!

Comment: @Rizier123, may be I don't get something. Could you take a look at the edit?

Answer (score 0):

In `_run.php`, you aren't letting any thrown Exception bubble up.  You have a `try`/`catch` block in there which swallows the exception and moves on.

Get rid of the `try`/`catch` in `_run.php`, and you will see your expected result.

Comment: The question is how (if possible) to catch "from above" already caught by nested script exception.

Comment: @ProstoTrader No, that's not possible.  You'd have to re-throw or remove the try/catch.

Comment: I can't remove try/catch, because nested script is doing some job in a loop, so even if part of the job causes erorrs, it should not fail on other loop parts.

Comment: Then why would you want to catch outside of it?  Put your try/catch blocks where they need to be.  Also, you should be throwing specific exception classes so that you can catch specific exceptions and let the rest bubble up.

Comment: Master script runs out 10 nested scripts and then saves stats to database. I just want to find out if there were any errors in nested scripts, count errors and save error logs to db.

Comment: If the exception is handled, then it isn't a problem.  If you intend for it to be something to be tracked, then you shouldn't be handling the exception.  Otherwise, log within these 10 nested scripts.  Provide a logger instance or interface to them.

Comment: Ok, there 200+ nested scripts actually. With lots of code, lots of exceptions. I dont want to rewrite all of them.

Comment: You have 200 scripts written incorrectly and you want to solve this with a magical code construct that doesn't exist?  I can't help you with that.  You need to consider refactoring.  There isn't enough context in your question to provide a specific refactoring suggestion.  Just follow the idea that exceptions are for exception-al events... not normal flow.  You don't *typically* want to be throwing exceptions for your normal flow of things (but you can if the circumstance deems it the best solution).  In any case, only catch what you intend to catch.  Refactor.  It's worth it.

Comment: They ARE written correctly. Try to get information from API for about 400000 clients from remote server and you'll find out that exceptios happen and they caused not by your code and you don't want to break cycle in such case.

Comment: @ProstoTrader In those cases you should be tracking an array of errors to return to the outer script for logging and handling.

Comment: Ok, whatever. You want me to rewrite all nested scripts :) I don't want to. I'd better rewrite Exception class.